# How does Islam see those who only offer eid prayers and jumma prayers?

Tags: sharia

If a person only performs eid and jumma prayers and is good with people and honest, how  does Islam see that person? Also, what could he face on the day of judgement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

There are so many good deeds we can do. There are so many sins we might commit.

In principle each person on earth has a different combination of good deeds and sins, should we ask a question for each of these combinations?

Allah, the Judge on the Day of Judgement, has helped us by laying down **principles** by which he judges, and they are clear from the Quran.

In some cases we might have a good guess of someone's fate according to Quran. If he keeps up regular prayer at perfect timing, performed haj, does charity, cares for family, tries to do everything Allah advocates and tries his best to stay away from the sins, then **very probably** he will be successful in the Hereafter. If one denies Allah's signs, commits zina regularly, is selfish and greedy, is violent and commits regularly other sins and he never repents his sins then it is **likely** that he belongs to the fire.

But **we are not 100% sure**, because Allah is the Judge, and He is the most forgiving. See the following hadith of a prostitute who was forgiven for her (previous) sins.

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>   The Prophet (PBUH) said, "While a dog was going round a well and was about to die of thirst, an Israeli prostitute saw it and took off her shoe and watered it. So Allah forgave her because of that good deed."
>
> حَدَّثَنَا سَعِيدُ بْنُ تَلِيدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا ابْنُ وَهْبٍ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنِي جَرِيرُ بْنُ حَازِمٍ، عَنْ أَيُّوبَ، عَنْ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ سِيرِينَ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ قَالَ قَالَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ بَيْنَمَا كَلْبٌ يُطِيفُ بِرَكِيَّةٍ كَادَ يَقْتُلُهُ الْعَطَشُ، إِذْ رَأَتْهُ بَغِيٌّ مِنْ بَغَايَا بَنِي إِسْرَائِيلَ، فَنَزَعَتْ مُوقَهَا فَسَقَتْهُ، فَغُفِرَ لَهَا بِهِ
>   Sahih al-Bukhari 3467

So what I am trying to say is, if you want to postulate about other's judgement, don't. Because you can't know for sure, Allah is the Judge. If you are worried about your own judgement, Allah knows everything we do and everything we conceal. So do as many good deeds (such as keeping up prayers at prescribed timing) as possible and refrain from sins as much as you can, why risk it?